# How to convert Json string to an Array - Android

Tags: android, json, string

I want to convert a Json string to an Array here is my current code

```
    String[] comments = json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT);
```

KEY_COMMENT is a string which contains multiple comments. The comments were gathered in a php array then sent back to the phone into a Json string. How can I convert the string to an array?

An example of what the comments look like is this

```
07-08 20:33:08.227: E/JSON(22615): {
"tag":"collectComments",
"success":1,
"error":0,
"numberOfComments":16,
"offsetNumber":1,
"comment":["test 16",
"test 15",
"test 14",
"test 13",
"test 12",
"test 11",
"test 10",
"test 9",
"test 8",
"test 7",
"test 6",
"test 5",
"test 4",
"test 3",
"test 2",
"test 1"]}n
```

Comment: Example json that is sent to the phone would be helpful.  But in general the comments are probabaly already and array.  You can use JSON.stringify(KEY_COMMENT) to see the raw format.

Comment: What do you mean by "JSON string"?  If you mean its a JSONArray of strings, you need to get it as a JSONArray and walk the array.  But you can only get it as a string if its a single string variable.

Comment: i added the json string which is inside KEY_COMMENTS. The part that is comment:test 1, test2,.... is what the variable KEY_COMMENTS holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [org.json library](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) and that you have already called the `public JSONObject(java.lang.String source)` string-based constructor to parse the full string into a local var named `json2`, presumably with something like this:

```
String json = ... // "{\"tag\":\"collectComments\",\"success\":1,...
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json);
String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";
```

but instead of `String[] comments = json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT);` (which tries to get the comments as a string; something that probably shouldn't work since it's an array, but does) you probably actually want:

```
JSONArray commentArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
```

At this point, `commentArray` is a JSONArray, which can be a heterogeneous list of values, including strings, numbers, booleans, nulls, and even arrays. If you want to turn this into an actual Java array of String, you'll need to walk it, converting as you go:

```
String comments[] = new String[commentArray.length()];
for ( int i=0; i<commentArray.length(); i++ ) {
    comments[i] = commentArray.getString(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found GSON a great tool to work with json objects on Android. It's a java library to convert JSON to Java object.

You can check it out here: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples

Here's their example working with Arrays:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String[] strings = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};

// Serialization
gson.toJson(ints);     ==> prints [1,2,3,4,5]
gson.toJson(strings);  ==> prints ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

// Deserialization
int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class);
```

In your case, you would set up the class as follow:

```
public class Comment {
    public String tag;
    public String[] comments; 
    // define other elements (numberOffset, error...) if needed
}
```

Then, to de-serialize the json response, in your code:

```
Comment item = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Comment.class); 
// Access the comments by 
String[] comments = item.comments;

// Access the tag
String tag = item.tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the default JSON lib try this:

// convert from json string to something useable
  JSONArray commentsArray = json2.JsonArray(KEY_COMMENT);

// loop through the elements
  int length = commentsArray.length()
  for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) 
  {
    String comment = commentsArray.getString(index);
    System.out.println(comment);
  }

For more information, I recomment this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/